# is there a reason for math.round *1000 /1000 doesn't make sense

Tags: java, javascript, android, math, rounding

I am looking at this line of code and I cannot make sense of it. This particular code is javascript, but I eventually would like to make a java android app.

```
$("#TxtHalfDot").val(Math.round((60000/bpm)*3*1000)/1000); 

         //bpm being a user entered value
```

I understand the process of the math and have been through it with a calculator many times. However, I can not make sense of the *1000 followed by /1000.

**My Question**

Is this a strange behavior of the "math.round" function or is it just simply not needed. I have seen it a lot but when I look at it I feel it can be omitted, but I am not a computer...

**(60000/bpm) * 3** gives the same result **((60000/bpm) *3*1000)/1000**

Comment: Just so we're clear javascript has no relation to java. Is this a pure javascript question?

Comment: `round(1.12345 * 1000) / 1000` should result in `1.234` if I'm not mistaken

Comment: `Math.round(1/3 * 1000) / 1000  !== Math.round(1/3) //true`

Comment: +1 for "but I am not a computer"

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 I think you mean `Math.round((1/3 * 1000)) / 1000 !== Math.round( 1/3 )`

Comment: @RichardTingle This is not a pure javascript question, the given code is javascript I understand the differences between java and java script I am just trying to make sense of this before I move over to starting my java app I only mentioned the use of java as people might have highlighted that this is only an anomaly with JS but it's not

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 and Juhana Thank you that makes a lot of sense so although they give very similar results to the computer they are different values

Comment: @gcoulby `0.333` (`~~(1/3 * 1E3) / 1E3`) is not very similar to `0` (`~~1/3`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Math.round(a*1000)/1000` results in number `a` rounded with 3 decimals.

Ex: Math.round(1234.123456 * 1000)/1000 = 1234.123

How this works is like this:
Suppose the number `a` has `x` decimals (in our example 6). You multiply the number by 10 to the power of `n` (in our example 3), effectively moving the decimal point `n` digits to the right. Then you round the number (cut all decimals). Then you divide by 10 to the power of `n`, moving the decimal point back.

Comment: Can you explain why there is 3 decimals, am I right in thinking if it was *100) / 100 it would give 2 decimals or do I not understand?

Comment: You are correct. The number of decimals equals to the base 10 logarithm of the number you multiply and divide by. I will explain in the answer.

Comment: Very thorough explanation. Proving that there is indeed a use for this (in a programming sense).

Comment: `Math.round(a*1000)/1000` results in **approximately** the number `a` rounded with three decimal digits after the point. Most numbers with three decimal digits cannot be represented exactly in the floating-point system using in JavaScript, so the result is only approximate.

Answer (score 9):

If you look carefully you find that the whole term is divided by 1000 *after* rounding.

So it is not just `x * 1000 / 1000`.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the parentheses.

```
Math.round((60000/bpm)*3*1000)/1000
```

In full it reads..

Divide 60000 by bpm then multiply by 3000 then perform Math.round then divide by 1000

You are rounding a possible float before dividing it by 1000